# Why is `moment` undefined here?

Tags: react-datepicker

I'm following this guide on using [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates). But when I try to use the `DayPickerRangeController`, I get this error message:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 27:38:  'moment' is not defined  no-undef
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'react-dates/initialize';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
import { DayPickerRangeController } from 'react-dates';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: null,
      focused: null
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <DayPickerRangeController
          startDate={this.state.startDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
          endDate={this.state.endDate} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null,
          onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
          focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
          onFocusChange={focusedInput => this.setState({ focusedInput })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired,
          initialVisibleMonth={() => moment().add(2, "M")} // PropTypes.func or null,
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**NOTE:** I was also following a video guide for reference, and they didn't install the dependencies (not sure why, but it seemed like they didn't need to for the `SingleDatePicker`). Could this be why I'm getting this error message? Or did I miss a step somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I just needed to `import moment from 'moment';`!

Answer (score 0):

### NodeJS: You should npm install the moment.js into you project.

or

### HTML:  you should import the moment.js before antd.js.

For Example:

```
    <script src="/assets/moment-2.24.0/monent.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/moment-2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/vue-2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
```